# CSS Selector for a previus div

Tags: css

```
<div class="main">
    <div class="content">
        <div class="content_hide">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="sidebar">
        <div class="single_sidebar">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is my HTML code. When I hover single_sidebar element, I want style `content_hide` div. something like

```
.single_sidebar:hover @@content_hide {background:red}
```

How can I select `content_hide` div by CSS when I hover `single_sidebar`?

Comment: If you change your markup so that the content_hide div comes after your sidebar div this can be easily done

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4502633/how-to-affect-other-elements-when-a-div-is-hovered

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently there's no way to do so in CSS. Maybe only in [CSS4 with `!`](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/selectors4/#subject).

You will have to incorporate JavaScript.

Just as an example, in jQuery:

```
$(".single_sidebar").on("mouseenter mouseleave", function(event) {
  $(this).closest(".main").find(".content_hide").toggleClass("someStyleClass");
});
```